# Can I prevent competitors from finding the links to my site by linking through an intermediate domain blocked from SEO tools?

Tags: seo, link-building, blackhat, competitors

I'm facing a problem where competitors constantly trying to steal my links by outreaching. This is also useful in a black hat scenario.

Create an intermediate domain, and redirect it to my main site, while blocking all bad bots e.g. ahrefs, majestic but not googlebot.

How good of an idea is it?

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but if they can simply make links on those sites then its likely your links are worthless in any case. Google does not value links on self-generating content sites like they use too. Platforms such as Forum Signatures, Article Submissions, Forum Profiles, WordPress/Joomla and other CMS comments, Pligg and even some Guest Blogging has taken a hit... enough of these will actually work against you... so let them... and focus on getting real links from real people where they simply can't get a link. Focus on gaining natural links, its those which count the most.

Comment: You can get editorial links to the redirected website as well. I'm more concerned about the idea of linking to a placeholder domain instead of your real one. For example some odd extention of the same domain to make it look legitimate, and asking editors to link to that instead

Comment: Can you explain more about "stealing links"?   I've never heard of that.

Comment: I also don't see how it would help unless you control all the inbound links to your site.   How are you going to change all the links to point to this second domain?

Comment: If a some service is offered, our competitor goes through every link on our link profile and asks the bloggers/companies to also link to them, since they provide similar service as an alternative.

Comment: OK, I've heard of that.   I wouldn't call that "stealing" though.

Comment: I'm not going to change other links, but all the new ones that I *buy* will be hidden. Of course, nothing I can do about natural links.

Comment: Technical term would be reverse engineering and you should know that Google is clamping down on people using second, third and fouth level domain linking to their money site, via both links and redirects. Its nothing new and is actually an outdated model. Also with PBN  (Private Blog Networks), they always goes to TITS... no matter what you read, sooner or later it catches up with you... unless you build own, why? because sellers want £££... But even own build PBN fail eventually and your domain is left hurt... for months, even years some don't recover... fact.

Comment: Blackhat is a short time thing and most of the people profitting from it nowadays isn't from Adsense clicks, its from selling software, links and PBN that have a limited life span on it.

Comment: Why not just blog the bots on your main domain?